# Telerik RadGrid GridButtonColumn not visible as Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

The push button is not visible for Reject. Instead it is showing as plain text.  Below is the code I have used for it.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvUpdate" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal"
    CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"         
    Width="382px" CellSpacing="0">
    <MasterTableView
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="15"
        CommandItemDisplay="Top"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id">

        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" DataType="System.Int64" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" UniqueName="Amount">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                   
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" HeaderText="Reject" Text="Reject" UniqueName="Reject" CommandName="Reject"></telerik:GridButtonColumn> 
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Could you please let me know what changes need to be done for the above code to make push button visible properly.

Comment: Is there anyone out there to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works for me

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Reject column" UniqueName="Reject" HeaderText="Reject" Display="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="Button1" runat="server" ButtonType="StandardButton" Text="Reject" CommandName="Reject" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have set `EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"`, the `GridButtonColumn` may not be rendered in a proper style.

What you can do is to apply your custom css to the `GridButtonColumn`, and style it to the way you wanted.

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" HeaderText="Reject" Text="Reject" UniqueName="Reject" CommandName="Reject" ButtonCssClass="YOUR CUSTOM CSS CLASS"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

Alternative approach

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" HeaderText="Reject" Text="Reject" UniqueName="Reject" CommandName="Reject"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
    { 
        var dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
            (dataItem["Reject"].Controls[0] as Button).CssClass = "MyButtonStyle"; 
    } 
}

<style type="text/css"> 
    .MyButtonStyle 
    { 
        background-color:black !important;
        color:white!important;
    } 
</style>
```

Using Custom Template

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" CommandName="Reject"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>
       </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.CommandName == "Reject")
       {
           var Id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
           // do something...
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have removed EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" but still it is appearing as Text. How can I apply in css to make it as normal button.

Comment: @CPK_2011 I have updated my answer and you could try the suggested alternative approach. See if that works for you or not.

Comment: But this does not work. It is adding a plain label with colors applied to it. I tried to apply <asp:Button../> inside the GridButtonColumn. This  also didn't work. Then I placed HTML Button <input type="Button"... It appeared fine. But how can i fire an event with HTML Button. I need an onclick event and bind the id of that row and get the results for it.

Comment: @CPK_2011 well, if that's the case, I guess you should try using GridTemplateColumn instead, where you can specify your own custom template there. Please find my updated answer again for example.

Comment: This GridTemplateColumn does not work either. The asp:Button is not visible at all. I want to override the skin applied to it and display it as normal button.

Comment: @CPK_2011 well it's working alright from my end though. I think you might have to check your code to see if the button or column is set to be invisible by default. I really doubt it's got something to do with the Telerik control itself though, but you could try upgrading it to the latest version and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your radgrid is always in EditForm mode, make sure that column has its ShowInEditForm property set to true.